# Excel userforms: mysterious behaviour of mouse events

Tags: excel, userform

I have a question concerning excel userforms and mouse events. I have a project with two userforms, userform1 and userform2. Userform2 is empty, no controls, no code. The codemodule of userform1 (which contains one textbox) contains the following code:

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
        Debug.Print "D (" & X & "," & Y & ")"
        UserForm2.Show False
    End Sub
    Private Sub TextBox1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
        Debug.Print "U (" & X & "," & Y & ")"
    End Sub
```

The problem: when i'm over the textbox and press the left mouse button, the mousedown event occurs but no mouseup event occurs when I release the mouse. Moreover the mouse seems to be captured as the next mouse press even if not on textbox1 generates a mousedown event for textbox1. 
I'm using Excel 2013 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with event propagation. You are capturing the `MouseDown` event. From the eventhandler of this event you are tearing away the focus from the element which has raised this event. So the event will probably bubble up to the new focused element.

With `Excel-VBA` we have not much possibilities to influence the event propagation. So we can't explicitly stopping the event propagation.

But why do you think you need showing the `UserForm2` from `MouseDown` event? Why not from `MouseUp` event? The problem is the same, but a `MouseUp` event will not do so much damage if bubbeling up to the wrong object.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
 Debug.Print "D (" & X & "," & Y & ")"
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
 Debug.Print "U (" & X & "," & Y & ")"
 Load UserForm2
 UserForm2.Show False
End Sub
```

Comment: Original idea: On Mousedown (over a textbox) to show a userform and to hide this userform on Mouseup. That simple. Any idea to accomplish this?

Comment: @Cord: But then how should the `UserForm2` be operated if it is only open while mouse pressed in `UserForm1`? Is the idea showing a tooltip text for the `TextBox` in `UserForm1`? If so see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821170.aspx. This works also with `Excel`.

Comment: Thank you. To clarify: Background for this question is: I have a form with many textboxes which have a very little font. You can read the text but its a bit hard. So the user should have the possibility to open a little form with an enlarged text by pushing and holding  a mousebutton as long as he wants. As the textboxes are not to be edited I can use labels instead. And as my tests have shown the envisaged technique functions es expected with labels.

Comment: Yes, a `Label` can't be focused. So with labels the focus can't be teared away. So the damage for the event propagation is not so bad.